# Is this expression 'does it have most' idiomatic?

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say my friend is eating a vegetable salad, It looks good so I want to what are the vegetables in it, Can I ask

> What(the vegetable) does this(the salad) have most?

similarly

> What does this movie have better, the script or the direction?

Does this construct sound weird to  native speakers?

Comment: 2nd sentence is sounding very weird to me. I guess we just ask *what is better, scipt or direction?* and not *what does this have better*.

Comment: In first sentence, I guess, we should add a *the* before *most*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the example sentences are ungrammatical.

Instead, these two will work:

> What vegetable has this salad got the most of?

> What does this movie have: better script or better direction?

However, I think both would benefit from using "is" instead of "has" because the focus is on a single ingredient, not on the whole. I think that's what's causing you to need these complex expressions, which are hard even for natives to get right. Compare these two:

> What is the main vegetable in this salad?

> In this movie, which is better: the script or the direction?

Comment: +1 for your last two revised sentences especially; those are far more natural ways to express this.

Answer (score -1):

In the first question, you are asking about the ingredients of a salad. If you are specifically interested in the relative proportions of one vegetable over others, you would probably have to be pretty specific. You'll also want to make sure to pair “most” with “of” in these situations, and introduce it with the definite article.

For example:

> **Ж** What vegetable does that salad have **the** most **of**?

It's pretty awkward, but could be understood.

A native speaker might instead ask:

> What's the **main** *(or **primary**)* vegetable in that salad?

If you just want a summary of the ingredients (“I want to [know] what [...] vegetables [are] in it”), then a good construction would simply be:

> What's in that?

---

Your second example is a little more difficult to evaluate. It is certainly not common to say it that way, but the construction isn't the only problem. “Better” is not a good parallel of “most”, and qualitative evaluations are generally going to go a little different from questions of quantity.

These two are grammatical, but awkward:

> **Ж** What is there **(the) most of** in that salad?

and, as closely parallel as possible:

> **Ж** What is there **better of** in the movie, writing or directing?

The latter is especially awkward.

You'd be better off saying this:

> What was better, the script or the directing? (= Which *did you like* better, the script or the directing?)

---

Not sure I've really addressed what you're looking for here. The short answer is “yes, that sounds weird to me as a native speaker”. Feel free to add examples or ask follow-up questions.

---

*In the answer above, a **Ж** ('Zhe') indicates an awkward construction that should be avoided.*

Comment: I don't think most native speakers would accept "*What is there better of in the movie, writing or directing" as proper English at all.

Comment: @GregHullender Nor do I, hence “especially awkward” and the suggested alternative. It's technically grammatical, though. I had hoped to shoehorn what I consider to be a more complicated, less applicable example into the format seemingly proposed by the question (esp. the title) in an effort to make a more generalizable point about these sorts of constructions.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to more clearly indicate that not all yellow boxes are viable as alternative phrasings.

Comment: @GregHullender If that's your downvote I see, is there anything more I could change to undo it? From your answer, it would seem that you completely agree with what I've said here.

Comment: Please don't take it personally. :-)  I just have a rule that whenever I see any post that I believe directs non-native speakers toward bad grammar, I always mark it down, no matter what any of the rest of the content was. Your post has a sentence marked "especially awkward" but which I think is flat-out ungrammatical (linguists would say "not English.")
Actually, putting my linguist hat back on, do you really *use* "*What is there better of" instead of "which is best" in your own speech?" Do you live somewhere where this expression is actually in common use?

Comment: @GregHullender I endeavor to never take anything personally, I just couldn't see much difference between our answers and thought you may have (perfectly understandably) missed the point I was struggling to make about these types of constructions. I think one thing that's really tough about the way this question is posed is that these two examples are too different for their mere corrections (which won't be similar to one another) to answer what the OP appears to be conceiving of as a general issue. I was hoping for a sort of _reductio ad absurdum_ effect.

Comment: @GregHullender To answer your question, I maintain that “what is there better of...” is not only a grammatical construction, it asks what I believe to be a better question. That is: “which is the greater success?” It suggests a (fairer) comparison between the script in question and all scripts, a second comparison between the direction in this movie and the direction in all movies, and then a third and final comparison between those two relative successes to decide which is the greater in its field. All of this is completely beside the point, of course, and no, I've never heard anyone say it.